# Using pandas Series as a value for a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine I wanted to store in a DataFrame the output of a set of runs of a given command.
Imagine that each run is defined by a list of key:value pairs (eg, the --key=value command-line args), all runs with the same list of keys, values will differ.

I can easily have a DataFrame where each run is a row and each key is a column, where each cell of these columns is the corresponding arg value. Now, for each row/run, I would like to have a special column 'results', which should contain all the results spit by the run (imagine, for simplicity, a list of floats is spit by each run).

Is using a Series nested in a DataFrame a good idea? Intuitively it feels like it will break some of the assumptions made by the DataFrame about its data model, and some operations won't work.

What is a better solution for my problem?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"key1": [1, 2], "key2": ["foo", "bar"], "results": [pd.Series([1., 2., 3.]), pd.Series([10., 20., 30.])})
```

Comment: Maybe you want a [pandas.Panel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html)?

Comment: "Is using a Series nested in a DataFrame a good idea" I would say no. While `pandas.Panel` is an option, I believe it is deprecated in favor of the [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) project